# Extending WebSocket Class

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to create my own WebSocket class.

```
function WebConnect(){
    WebSocket.call(this, "wss://ws.achex.ca/")
}

WebConnect.prototype = Object.create(WebSocket.prototype);

WebConnect.prototype.onopen = function(evt){ console.log(evt) }

...

WebConnect.prototype.anotherWsFunction = function(){...}
```

But when I try to create this class `var a = new WebConnect()` I'm getting stuck on this error :
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function."

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to do it this way, because I'd like to have defined **"onopen, onclose,.."** events already defined plus some custom methods when I create this class, so I can use them later in another class

```
function SOCKET(props){
    this.websocket = new WebConnect();
    this.lobby = new Lobby();
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

```
class WebConnect extends WebSocket {
    constructor(wsuri) {
        super(wsuri)
    }

    onopen(event) {
        console.log("Connection open event:");
        console.log(event);
    }

    onclose(event) {
        console.log("Connection closed event:");
        console.log(event);
    }

    onerror(event) {
        console.log("Connection error event:");
        console.log(event);
    }

    onmessage(event) {
        console.log("Message event:");
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

after @PatrickRoberts comment ES6 class approach isn't working too
if `var a = new WebConnect(wsuri)` then `a.onopen == null`

EDIT: 
Any ideas please? Right now I'm using wrapper. But is it possible to do it "class extend" way?

Comment: You can't extend `WebSocket` using the ES5 approach, as it's a strict constructor function and does not allow calls without `new`. You'll need to use ES6 `class` syntax and invoke `super()` which properly sets `new.target` within the constructor function in order to extend it without erroring.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts
`class WebConnect extends WebSocket {
    constructor(wsuri) {
        super(wsuri)
    }

    onopen(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    onclose(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
    onerror(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    onmessage(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}`
I also tried this but after `var a = new WebConnect(uri)` function `a.onopen == null`

Comment: @Chiffre Probably the `WebSocket` constructor creates an own `onopen` property on the instance, shadowing the inherited one from your prototype. Instead, initialise your stuff inside the constructor, either by assignment to `this.on*` or by using `this.addEventListener(…)`. However, using a wrapper class is probably the wisest choice. What does your `WebConnect` do?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in Safari; I seem to be able to extend the WebSocket class successfully in Chrome, but in Safari the methods I implement in the extended class seem to be `undefined` when attempting to access them, despite them showing in the class' `prototype`